# Get a value by ID in JSON alike structure?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I need to retrieve an object by `id` in variable created by some JSON data.
At the moment I am using the following script, search is done using  `for .. in` looking at each property for each object.

I would like to know:

- If there is any faster way to retrieve the object with a specific `id`?
- What is the most efficient way to find the parent node of id:3
- What type of tree structure this data represents?

http://jsbin.com/jebukameci/1/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <script>
      var data =  {
     id: 0,
      cnt: [
        {
          id: 1,
          cnt: [
            {
              id: 2,
              cnt: [
                {
                  id: 3,
                  cnt:[]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },

      ]
    };



    function getById (id) {
                function getByIdInner(obj, id) {
                    var result;
                    for (var p in obj) {
                        if (obj.id == id) {
                            return obj;
                        } else {
                            if (typeof obj[p] === 'object') {
                                result = getByIdInner(obj[p], id);
                                if (result) {
                                    return result;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return result;
                }
                return getByIdInner(this.data, id);


   }



    </script>

</head>

<body onload="(function(){console.log(getById(3))})();">


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: a Faster way? no, other than knowing the path beforehand. Easier, yes, through the use of 3rd party libraries that will do the looping for you.

Comment: *"What type of tree structure this data represents"* I don't think this object structure has a specific name. It's an object with nested objects and arrays.

Comment: @JamesThorpe thanks James for your comment, previous question was about the parent id... should I merge the questions? Thanks all for your time!

Comment: @JamesThorpe thanks James, I have edited the question, not know if merging question is allowed on SO after creation.

Comment: @JamesThorpe Thanks, I followed your advice I will delete when possible this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28188947/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-get-the-parent-node-for-child-from-variable-ba